# Automapper's Ignore option setting destination property to NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

In my Global.asax:

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, DataType>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.User, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

In my MVC Action:

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(viewmodel, data);
```

Prior to calling the Map() function, data.User is not null.  Immediately after calling Map(), data.User is now null, however, if I am understanding correctly, Ignore() should completely ignore that property and leave it untouched.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clearly didn't give enough information for anyone to solve this.

My problem happened to occur because my data model is an EF4 Entity, and my View Model had a mapping to a Foreign Key that was mapped to the User object mentioned above.  Once we call Map(), it reset the User entity to null.  Once I removed this property from my ViewModel, everything began working as expected.